# How to access application settings from a model in Padrino

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I'm tring to do something basic in Padrino, but lots of searching hasn't come up with any answers.  I'm trying to access a global setting from a model.  I have added a line to the "development" section of the environments.yaml file called "endpoint", how do I access this setting from a model class?  Is environments.yaml the best file to use for this kind of setting?

```
environments:
  development:
    endpoint: 'http://192.168.56.1:3001'
```

When I try using "settings.endpoint" in a model function, I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `settings' for Country:Class
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would use environment variables:

```
environments:
  development:
    endpoint: <%= ENV["ENDPOINT"] %>
```

Then in your ruby code you can access it with `ENV['ENDPOINT']`.

See how to set environments variables in a `.env` file with a gem such as [Dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

Comment: Thanks, using environment variables means I don't need a yaml configuration file though, so the `endpoint: <%= ENV["ENDPOINT"] %>` is redundant.

Comment: Well I'm not an expert about Padrino but in rails some .yml files are mandatory whether you use env vars or not.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you asked for, but here's how I solved this for settings that are *not* environment-specific:

Specify the setting in `config/apps.rb`:

```
Padrino.configure_apps do
  set :foobar, 42
end
```

You should then be able to get the value with:

```
MyApp::App.settings.foobar # => 42
```

This is, of course, assuming your Padrino app is called `MyApp` (you can check in `app/app.rb` if you're not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Padrino 0.13.2

`Padrino.mounted_apps[0].app_obj.settings.endpoint`

There may be more than 1 apps mounted. I've not tested yet with multiple apps. Please comment for fix if you have discovered more.